# How are older questions with an answer not accepted resolved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

For example, [this question was originally solved by the OP](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233365), which they put within their question. I took the liberty to separate that as an answer.

> Since this question has been essentially resolved, but not accepted by the OP, how does that work? Will the answer get accepted over time? We we flag it? Or will it forever be in the digital graveyard of unaccepted questions?

#### Update: a possibly new feature?

[Per toscho's ♦ response](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4254/98212):

> As soon as an answer is upvoted, the question does not count anymore as "unanswered".

As someone who uses issue tracking platforms (such as [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira)), this won't settle well with my *need-for-some-closure*.

Much like how anyone with 500+ rep can review Q/A by new users, I think it would be worth adding a new feature to allow the community to help put some closure on some questions that were not officially accepted by the OP, but clearly solves the question. Essentially, override the OP and manually accept the best answer.

Comment: In relation to your edit with the new feature request - this has been asked many times before on the StackExchange platform, and it's not going to happen: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period. As toscho said, voting takes cares of this though - an upvoted answer marks the question as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as an answer is upvoted, the question does not count anymore as "unanswered". So please continue answering these questions, the upvotes will come over time. :)

Comment: I see. So having the OP's green checkmark next to the answer isn't entirely necessary? So long as the answer is upvoted by the community?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Exactly. Many askers don't bother giving the checkmark, they just grab the solution and run away with it. :/

Comment: This won't settle well with my need-for-some-closure. Much like how anyone with 500+ rep can review a new Q/A by new users, I think this would be worth adding a feature to allow the community to help put some closure to questions that were not officially accepted by the OP, but clearly solves the question. Essentially override the OP and manually accept the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was on this question that I rejected Ethan's edit where he removed the OP's answer from the question, because that was clearly not OP's intent.

On the other hand, I applaud the initiative to get it answered. So, would it be better to allow such edits?

Comment: This is where I see the dilemma on whether to flag it for a moderator close it or have the changes made myself, like I attempted to do. As I mention in my original post, I'd like have these questions with some closure to improve the community's records.

Comment: I voted to approve this edit, because I believe it completely followed the askers intent: they wanted to provide the answer; it is entirely appropriate to move the answer from the question to an answer _if_ they have had ample time to do so themselves, and there was already a comment on the question from last month asking them to do just that. It's the kind of edit I would have made if I came across it too. I see the edit has been rejected because it got two rejected votes though; if you agree with this rationale perhaps one of us can re-edit the answer.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I wouldn't flag for a moderator, as this sort of thing can be solved by the community. As noted above I _think_ you did the right thing (and I would have done it too); once you have 2k rep your edits are applied automatically without needing approval so that threshold makes it a little easier to do this sort of cleanup.

Comment: @TimMalone Thanks. So I'll continue to do edits like the question above? Good to know about the 2k rep perk. But I still think it would be worth adding a new feature to have closure on some questions that were not officially accepted by the OP, but it's clearly solved.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Just hang on for a bit for others to respond on that point in case I'm wrong ;) And re the new feature, it won't happen, see the comment I added on your question or search meta.stackexchange for the many times it's been asked.